# How to resize a svg to fit inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

on trying fitting in to div(with border) svg is cut off from the right size.

**[PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZAJLL)**

**HTML**

```
 <div style="position:relative;width:550px;height: 500px;background: gainsboro;border: 4px solid;">

 <-- My SVG -->

 </div>
```

help me fit this svg in 550x500

Comment: The `viewBox` of svg should be in aspect ratio of 550X550.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `width` or `height` in your SVG.

Use `viewbox` instead. Then the SVG will scale automatically (mostly).

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox ="0  0 959 593">`

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NAvkkj/)